# Create a message similar to p:messages using PrimeFaces without adding to FacesContext?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 2.3.0 and JSF2.0.

I like the html output that Primefaces `p:messages` gives me.  But I due to existing design, I would like to create the html without needing the to add the messages using `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage`.

Essentially, I would like to do something like this:

```
<p:messages value="test"/>
```

I realize probably would not use p:messages but an existing tags that just outputs something very similar to what p:messages outputs.

I am hoping there is maybe another component that `p:messages` is using.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: do you want to show static message text as value (like in your example) or the message text is coming from your backing bean?

Comment: You can just use the same html generated by p:messages. For usage: see this answer [error-message-style-for-a-panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370481/error-message-style-for-a-panel)

Comment: have you found a solution, could you share with us?

Comment: So far I have not found a solution that does not involved adding the faces messages.

Answer (score 13):

The most minimalistic example I've found that looks exactly the same using my theme is:

```
<div class="ui-message-error">
    <span class="ui-message-error-icon"/>
    <span class="ui-message-error-detail">test</span>
</div>
```

I've removed classes `ui-widget ui-corner-all` from div, because I don't use rounded corners etc., but if it makes a difference in your case, well, the example would be a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the StaticMessage component

```
  <p:staticMessage severity="info" summary="INFO!" detail="Hey, i'm a info!" />
```

See https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/staticMessage.xhtml

Comment: Can you please add from what version info this is supported?