# Primefaces Label with theme specific warnings

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Primefaces has messages with theme specific labels for different levels like info, warning and error.

Can we use a label without using messages ourselves which looks exactly like the messages of that particular theme.

For example, when an expired item is listed in a autocomplete, the data of expiry will be listed like an error message. It needs to be specific to the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the class that primefaces provide to customise the message. Example :

```
<p:outputLabel value="something" styleClass="ui-messages-error-summary" />
```

You can use firebug or similar tools to find out which css class to use.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate Question. Please refer to [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370481/error-message-style-for-a-panel)

```
<div class="ui-message-error ui-corner-all">
      <span class="ui-message-error-icon"/>
      <span class="ui-message-error-detail">your message here</span>
</div>
```